# Very strange issue with String and Double

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

```
string TestVarStrg = "3.1";
double TestVarDoub = Convert.ToDouble(TestVarStrg);

MessageBox.Show(TestVarDoub.ToString());
```

with this code I get within the message box on the emulator "31". same on my lumia 920. but on my lumia 1520  I get "3.1". bouth devices have the last lumia black update. anyway actually I need "3.1" as double. "31" would be ok too but on all devices please. any idea about this behavior? Or an other way to convert string to double?

Comment: A significant part of the world spells "decimal point" as "comma".  It isn't very clear why your Lumia still think it is in Sweden.  You must use CultureInfo.InvariantCulture to avoid such accidents.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please consider that the decimal sign is dependent on the culture settings. Use the overload where you can provide an IFormatProvider:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/9s9ak971(v=vs.110).aspx

So your code would look like:

```
string TestVarStrg = "3.1";
double TestVarDoub = Convert.ToDouble(TestVarStrg, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

MessageBox.Show(TestVarDoub.ToString());
```

Please consider that this only works if your decimal sign is always a ".".